# PHP OOP CLASS chaining

Tags: php, oop

I have seen people do this:

```
$controller->bar->stuff->foo();
```

I suppose this is CLASS chaining?

How is this achievable? (if at all achievable)

NOTE. I am not asking about method chaining.

Cheers!

EDIT: Forgot to ask this... how would this benefit me? If you guys could write a short example it'd be great!

Comment: There is no such thing as "class chaining". `$controller` has a property `bar`; whatever is in it has a property `stuff`; whatever is in *there* has a method `foo`; and this method will be invoked.

Answer (score 4):

This is achieved via accessible properties. For example, using `public` properties...

```
class Stuff {
    public function foo() {}
}

class Bar {
    /**
     * @var Stuff
     */
    public $stuff;

    public function ___construct(Stuff $stuff) {
        $this->stuff = $stuff;
    }
}

class Controller {
    /**
     * @var Bar
     */
    public $bar;

    public function __construct(Bar $bar) {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}

$stuff = new Stuff();
$bar = new Bar($stuff);
$controller = new Controller($bar);

$controller->bar->stuff->foo();
```

I wouldn't recommend this as it leaves your classes open to external modification. Another method might be via magic *getter* methods, for example

```
class Controller {
    private $properties = [];

    public function __construct(Bar $bar) {
        $this->properties['bar'] = $bar;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        return array_key_exists($name, $this->properties)
            ? $this->properties[$name] : null;
    }
}
```

This means you can still access the property in the private `$properties` array like it was a public property (eg `$controller->bar`) without it being open to external modification.

In my opinion though, keep properties private / protected and provide accessor methods

```
class Controller {
    /**
     * @var Bar
     */
    private $bar;

    public function __construct(Bar $bar) {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    /**
     * @return Bar
     */
    public function getBar() { return $this->bar; }
}

$controller->getBar()->someBarMethod()->etc();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've got one more question. Not sure if you have ever used CodeIgniter, but... CI has something similar - $this->input->post()... is this achieved the same way?

Comment: I've never used CI. I suggest you dig into the [source code](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/) if you want to find out. From what I've seen, I certainly wouldn't hold it up as a beacon of good OOP.

Comment: +1 for the great explanation. Just a side question, would the second block of code be better suited as a registry object? :)

Comment: @Darren That pattern could be used as a registry but I was really only  trying to show how the magic `__get` method works.